# How to display multiple values entered in dynamically created input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am calling this method addpoc() which creates a block of input boxes and a dropdown. And on the selection of dropdown option personal/workmail an input box is appearing.

2)when I am adding multiple enteries into the different input block and then trying to displaying on screen it takes the first input entry only
multiple times. PLease let me know where i am going wrong.
Edit: I tried other solutions on stackoverflow, not seem to be working for my usecase

```js
//code to delete the input block
$('body').on('click', '.delbtn', function(e) {
  $(this).closest(".contactIp").remove();
});
//function to add the input block
function addpoc() {
  let el = '';
  el += '<div class="contactIp"><div><div class="name"><label for="fname">First name:</label><br><input type="text" class="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ricky"></div><div class="name"><label for="lname">Last name:</label><br><input type="text" class="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ju"></div></div><div class="parent" style="width: 100%;"><div id="one"><select id="contact method" onchange="showMail(this)"><option disabled selected>Prefered contact method</option><option value="workmail">Work email </option><option value="personalmail">Personal Email</option></select></div><div class="two" id="two" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="workemail" placeholder="Work email"></div><div class="three" id="three" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="personalemail" placeholder="Personal email"></div></div><br><br> <div><button class="delbtn"><span class="inbtn">&times</span>Delete</button></div></div>'

  $('.addelement').append(el);
}

function showMail(selecteop) {
  var first = $(".fname").val();
  var second = $(".lname").val();
  var workemail1 = $(".workemail").val();
  var personalemail1 = $(".personalemail").val();
  document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML += '<br>' + first + " " + second;
  if (selecteop.value == "workmail") {
    document.getElementById("contact_mail").innerText = workemail1;
    $(selecteop).closest(".parent").find(".two").show();
    $(selecteop).closest(".parent").find(".three").hide();

  } else {
    $(selecteop).closest(".parent").find(".three").show();
    $(selecteop).closest(".parent").find(".two").hide();
    document.getElementById("contact_mail").innerHTML = personalemail1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Where can we reach YOU?</h1>
  <div class="addelement">
    <div class="contactIp">
      <div>
        <div class="name"><label for="fname">First name:</label><br><input type="text" class="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ricky"></div>
        <div class="name"><label for="lname">Last name:</label><br><input type="text" class="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ju"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="parent" style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="one">
          <select id="contact method" onchange="showMail(this)">
            <option disabled selected>Prefered contact method</option>
            <option value="workmail">Work email </option>
            <option value="personalmail">Personal Email</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="two" id="two" style="display: none;">
          <input class="workemail" type="email" name="workemail" placeholder="Work email">
        </div>
        <div class="three" id="three" style="display: none;">
          <input class="personalemail" type="email" name="personalemail" placeholder="Personal email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div style="width:100%">
    <button style="width:100%" id="addbtn" onclick="addpoc()">Add another point of contact</button>
  </div>

</div>
<p id="contact"></p>
<p id="contact_mail"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: ya i tried doing the similar way aswell, no luck

Answer (score 0):

So your deleteInp function deletes the first item on the page.  That's probably not what you want.  I suggest changing the call to pass `this` as a parameter (the value will be the button that was clicked), then use that parameter to find the closest contactIp:

```
<button onclick="deleteInp(this)">

function deleteInp(theButton) {
  $(theButton).closest(".contactIp").remove();
}
```

Again with your showMail function, you are pulling the first "firstName" which appears on the page, instead of the one that corresponds to the clicked button.  You are already passing `this`.  So do something like

```
var first = $(selecteop).closest(".fname").val();
```

Comment: no both of them not seem to be working

Comment: thanks, delete functionality works after few tweaks